# Is there a way to send Payload in HTTP Delete in WSO2 EI v6.4

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am currently trying to access any REST service for deleting a resource from my WSO2 EI sequence. The code looks something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="DELETE_COMPANY_INFO" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="Sequence" value="DELETE COMPANY INFO started"/>
    </log>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="json-eval($)" name="Request Payload"/>
    </log>
    <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="set" value="false" type="BOOLEAN" scope="axis2"/>
    <call blocking="true">
        <endpoint>
            <http method="delete" uri-template="http://<IP>:<Port>/companyinfo/<id>">
           </http>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
</sequence>
```

As can be seen I wish to send the message payload to this endpoint. However I am not able to send this as the payload is dropped by WSO2 EI v6.4
Logs are below

```
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,127] [micro-integrator]  INFO - LogMediator Sequence = DELETE COMPANY INFO started
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,128] [micro-integrator]  INFO - LogMediator Request Payload = {"CompanyName":"test123"}
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,131] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header >> "DELETE /companyinfo/123 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,131] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,132] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,132] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header >> "Host: <IP>:<Port>[\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,132] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header >> "[\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,136] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header << "HTTP/1.1 200 [\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,136] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header << "HTTP/1.1 200 [\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,136] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,136] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header << "Content-Length: 25[\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,137] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header << "Date: Fri, 21 Feb 2020 08:30:32 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,137] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - header << "[\r][\n]"
[2020-02-21 14:00:33,137] [micro-integrator] DEBUG - content << "{"CompanyName":"test123"}"
```

I know that REST Webservice implementation **should** not use Payload for HTTP DELETE operation, however I think ESB **should** not make the decision to drop the Payload if the underlying transport allows it.
Additionally, I know that this issue was reported earlier (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-5060) and marked as resolved in v6.2 of WSO2 EI. However I am facing this in 6.4 version of EI.

Is there a solution to allow Payload with HTTP DELETE call using Call Mediator in WSO2 EI v6.4?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the fix has gone to the Passthrough transport (non blocking) and not to the blocking transport. If you remove the blocking="true" mode, it should work.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working now. However, this behavior is also a bit problematic. I wish to not ack the caller unless I have response for this DELETE call. When using non-blocking mode, the DELETE call happens in new thread and my caller is acked immediately. I am not sure why this behavior is implemented only in non-blocking mode? Any comments are helpful.